# Find tilt of ellipse using max and min values

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

I have an ellipse given in parametric form (shown below). I need to find the tilt of the ellipse $\delta$. However, I only know 4 values on the ellipse: $y_{max} = A_y +B_y$, $x_{max} = A_x +B_x$, $y_{min} = A_y -B_y$, and $x_{min} = A_x -B_x$. How can I find $\delta$ in terms of these 4 values?

$$
x = A_x + B_x \cos(t)
$$
$$
y = A_y + B_y \sin(t+\delta)
$$

Edit: I also know the x,y value of each extreme point.

Comment: You can’t without more information. The bounding box is clearly the same for all values of $\delta$.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much! However, if I also know the x and y coordinate of each extreme point that lies on the ellipse then I should be able to figure it out as well, right? For example, if the very upper point is perfectly above the very lower point, then there must be no tilt $\delta =0$. Presumably, $\delta$ can be found by using the geometry between the 4 pairs of points then right?

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You only need the coordinates of one of the extrema. For instance, the maximum $x$ value occurs when $t=0$, which then gives you an equation for $\sin\delta$ from the corresponding $y$ coordinate.

Comment: I manged to solve it.

$$\delta = asin(\frac{y-A_y}{B_y}) - acos(\frac{x-A_x}{B_x})$$

Where all the A's and B's can be easily found in terms of $x,y_{max,min}$, and the $x$ and $y$ terms in the equation can be substituted for literally any point on the ellipse.